# Let $\lambda_n=1-1/n$ for $n=1,2,\dots.$ Show that there cannot be a regular or periodic Sturm-Liouville problem having these numbers as eigenvalues.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sturm-liouville

How does one show that this is true? I assume it has to do with the properties of the y solutions since they are either $y(x)=c_1e^{kx}+c_2e^{-kx}$, where $\lambda=-k^2, k<0$; or $y(x)=c_1\cos(kx)+c_2\sin(kx)$ where $\lambda=k^2, k>0.$

Comment: For any regular sturm-liouville problem on a finite interval with either separated or periodic conditions, the eigenvalues are the zeroes of an entire function, which guarantees that the eigenvalues cannot have any finite point of accumulation.

Comment: Were you able to resolve your question? If you want more specifics, please post the specific Sturm-Liouville problem that you're interested in, and I'll try to be very specific about the details that I mentioned.

Comment: I don't think I did, but it's okay